# MacOS icons missing in the Dock (10.14 Mojave)

Tags: macos, system, macos-mojave

I just updated to Mojave, and I see my downloads folder on Dock no longer shows any icons. How to fix it?

Here's I've tried to fix so far:

1. I've tried cleaning using Clean My Mac
2. Disabled and Enabled Icon preview on Finder > View > Show View Options
3. Tried `killall Dock` in terminal

   [image: Dock screenshot]

Comment: Does it append only in the dock?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting. It is still an issue?

Comment: @SantoshAchari I downvoted because the question is off topic for this site as it's not about programming. http://apple.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: I have that issue system wide not only in the dock

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1: Move your dock plist to your desktop**

You can try to revert your dock preferences to **default**:

1. In `Menu > Go (press option) > Library > Preferences`,
2. Find and **move** to your desktop:

   - `com.apple.dock.plist` (this one must exist)
   - `com.apple.dock.extra.plist` (if exists)
   - `com.apple.dock.db.plist` (if exists)
3. then **log out** and then **log in** (or simply **restart**).

**Method 2: Restart with Safely Mode**

If the above steps are not working, try the following:

1. Start or restart your computer in `safety Mode`. To do that:

   - Hold the `shift key` until you see the Apple logo
   - Release the key
   - Log into your session
2. Restart in `normal mode`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it!

Comment: Didn't work for me. Just reverted icon set and preferences to default. By the way, 'com.apple.dock.extra.plist' didn't exist.

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich: I have checked, it does exist. If you do a `$ ls /Library/Preferences/ | grep com.apple.dock.plist` it should give you a result.

Comment: @KeyMaker00 Made as you said, The result is only `com.apple.dock.plist`, grepping `com.apple.dock.` returned the same. So I definitely don't have `com.apple.dock.extra.plist` .

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich: I have extended my answer. Let me know if it has worked for you.

Comment: @KeyMaker00 Method1 finally worked for me. And what's interesting - the dock's preferences didn't go back to defaults this time. Hopefully, the bug won't appear, as it used to behave variously, making some icons transparent selectively either all of them. Thanks for extending the answer.

Comment: @FedorAlexandrovich: glad to hear it. I have read that Apple will release soon `10.14.1` which is already in beta. Hopefully it will fix this issue.

Comment: If you use CleanMyMac - rebuilding startup indexes should also fix this.

Comment: I have that issue system wide not only in the dock

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the icon cache in macOS. The easiest way to do that is to:

1.) Right click the app and chose "Get Info”.

2.) Drag ANYTHING to its icon in the top left of the "Get Info" window (you can drag a FOLDER to its icon if you want to) to assign a new temporary icon.

3.) CLICK the icon in the "get info" window and press BACKSPACE to clear it.

That forces macOS to re-read the .icns file inside the bundle itself and it will cache the new one.